# Write data in HTML object tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to replace the Iframes in my project with with object tag for some reason.

The working code with iframe is :

```
var iframeDoc = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document;
var html = "html string code "//html page source code;
iframeDoc.write(html);
iframeDoc.close();
```

Can some please help me in replacing above code with object?

Comment: "I want to replace the Iframes in my project with with object tag for some reason" — What is that reason? It's almost always a bad idea. The behaviour of iframes when dealing with HTML is much better understood.

Comment: That code isn't valid. `<br>` is HTML, the rest is javascript. HTML inside a javascript code isn't permitted (although the opposite is).

Comment: @DonaldDuck — It was valid before John Slegers reformatted it

Answer (score -1):

```
var iframe=document.getElementById("youriframe");//get the iframe
iframe.parentNode.insertBefore(obj=document.createElement("object"),iframe);//insert the obj at the iframes position
iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);//remove iframe
obj.innerHTML="test";//work with the obj
```

I think the code is selfexplaining...

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nogatok/1/edit?html,js,output — It doesn't work (although it does throw a syntax error).

Comment: Even without the syntax error, `<div>` is not `<object>` (the question only mentioned using objects three times and divs not at all)

Comment: @Quentin: oh sorry,fixed